# Integrating FBA (or Amazon MWS) with Ubercart

Tags: 8, ubercart

I am going to be rebuilding an ecommerce site in Drupal 8 using [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart).  The site was originally built with Drupal 6 and [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) and had Amazon FWS integrated into the store.  Is there anything similar I can use for Drupal 8?  Basically the client needs FBA (fulfillment by Amazon) integrated into the site.

Answer (score 0):

There's Commerce Amazon fulfillment if you're not wedded to Ubercart, but it needs porting to D8.